# RailsBestPractices - overuse route customizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Before all**, it's not a question about a best practices, I know you don't like it in SO. Read my question before unlike it !

I'm using the gem `rails_best_practices` to detect some wrong practices on my projects. Recently, I had several "overuse route customizations" (http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/22/overuse-route-customizations/).

My route looks like this :

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get :featured
    get :computed
    get :static
    get :blocked
  end
```

The actions linked to theses routes are just a specific `index` with a state scope, like this :

```
def featured
  @projects = Project.featured.paginate(...)
end
```

I use theses routes to have beautiful URL like `/projects/featured` instead of `/projects/?state=featured`

My question is how to change theses current routes to have the same behaviour with *beautiful* URLs ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the stories resource

```
get '/projects/:state', to: 'projects#index', constraints: { state: /featured|computed|static|blocked/ }
```

Or inside:

```
collection do
  get '/projects/:state', to: 'projects#index', constraints: { state: /featured|computed|static|blocked/ }
end
```